# will using Docker allow me to not install necessary requisites?

Tags: docker, ros2

I am a bit confused about Docker and how can I use it. My situation is the following:

I have a project that requires the use of a requisite, in my case installing ROS2. I have installed it in my system and develop a program. No problem there.

I wish to upload it to Gitlab and use CICD there. So I am guessing I will push it to my repository and then build a pipeline where I can use as image the docker image for ROS 2. I haven't tried it yet (will do it tomorrow) but I guess that is how I should do it.

My question is, can I do something similar (or how to ) in my local machine? In other words, just use the docker image and then develop and build over there and not install the requisite in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I heartily agree that using docker to develop locally improves the development experience, primarily by obviating system specific dependency management, just as you say.

Exactly how this is done depends on how many components you need to develop simultaneously, and how you want the development environment to behave .

An obvious place to start might be docker compose, a framework for starting multiple docker containers.  https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ looks like quite a nice tutorial on the subject, and straight from the horse's mouth too.

However, your robotics project (?) may not be a very good fit for the server/client model behind the write - restart python - execute client - debug - repeat cycle in the document. To provide a better answer, we'd need a lot more understanding of how exactly your local development works - what exactly you want your development process to look like in this project might require a different solution.  So add some workflow details to your question!